# Select difference of same value as of two dates from single table

Tags: sql

i have a select query selecting different columns and for one column i have to get a value from a table as of today and previous year end and should take the difference. Assume that this table stores values everyday suppose it to be X.

```
select a
       b
       c
       d
       e

e= ( SELECT VALUE FROM X WHERE DATE='TODAY') MINUS ( SELECT VALUE FROM X WHERE DATE='PREVIOUS YEAR END') i.e 31-dec-2013
```

Can some one please tell me the logic how same value as of different dates can be selected in single select query

Comment: What is your table structure?  What is your desired result?  This would be very hard to answer without some context.

Comment: it is just a select query selecting from different tables but i have a calculated column after selecting n columns after writing select a,b,c,d i have e where e=balance as todays date (-) minus as of year end

Comment: I think a self join is what you're looking for.

Comment: i already have 6 joins in my select query and various cases like case when x then y etc... after selecting all columns i have to get a value based on one table i have the joining condition but i can specify only single where condition for date. i want two take difference of value between to dates

Comment: To be simple consider.. i have a select query selecting different columns and for one column i have to get a value from a table as of today and previous year end. Assume that this table stores values everyday suppose it to be X. NOW ( SELECT VALUE FROM X WHERE DATE='TODAY') MINUS ( SELECT VALUE FROM X WHERE DATE='PREVIOUS YEAR END' i.e 31-dec-2013

Comment: I've down voted your question because it violates some of the rules on here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Boss Jonny that's the reason stackoverflow has edit button to make it clear if users can't get what the question is... better you rethink before tagging down posts

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE*

After rereading your edit it looks like you want to use a sub select to get `e`. In that case here's your selects with the same logic to solve for EOY last year.

```
( SELECT VALUE FROM X WHERE DATE=getdate()) - 
( SELECT VALUE FROM X WHERE DATE=DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), -1))
```

My original answer below uses one table and joins it on itself.

---

You could do something like this. Just specify the date in there where clause. The `join` links `the date` to `EOY date last year`.

```
select 
    a.date as 'aDate',
    a.value as 'aValue',
    b.value as 'lastEOYValue',    
    a.value - b.value as 'Diff'
  from x a
  join x b 
    on b.date = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,a.date), -1) --links EOY last year
```

[SQL Fiddle Example HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a401b/3)

Comment: Thanks Jchao but Value has to be from same table not different table

Comment: @user3826067 Please see my updated answer. Both solutions only user a single table. The second solution just joined a table on itself.

Comment: sorry it will not allow to write like                            select a,                                                             b,                                                                 c,                                                                            d                                                                     (select value from x where date)-(select value from x where yearenddate) as Balance                                            this is one of the column I'm selecting Oracle will accept nested queries not like this